# python how to logging all third-party log into a seperate file

Tags: python, logging, sqlalchemy

for my perspective, I would initialize a logger to log message for my app

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('my_app') 
handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(
    '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

when errors happend:

```
try:
    blah()
except Exceptions as e:
    logger.warning(e)
```

But I'm using some third-party module like sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy may log  warning infos when error happends(e.g, varchar is too long and being truncated) and it use a separate logger (so does some other modules, like requests)
    [sqlalchemy/log.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbYVu.png)

This may leads some bad issues and it's not trackable.
In case I'm using lots of third-party modules, how can I log all third-party message to a separate file to help me doing trouble shooting works?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a handler to log to a file and attach that to the root logger, but that will log *all* messages, even ones from your code. To leave your messages out of that file, use a `logging.Filter` subclass which filters out all messages which aren't from one of your code's top-level package namespaces. Attach that filter to your handler.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you help, can you kindly show me a code sample? Thank you.